# openerp override onchange behavior without affecting base

Tags: odoo

I have inherited from purchase.order.line. I have added a bunch of related fields. They are all related to fields in product.product via product_id in order_line.

What I want to achieve is that when a user selects or changes a product in the purchase order line form, the related fields should get refreshed/updated/populated with values of the selected product.

I have written the onchange method for this but I'm not sure how to invoke it from the inherited view? The product_id field was already there in the (parent) order_line view and it already has an onchange defined. How do I get the system to use my onchange as well?

I don't want to disturb the onchange_productid method that is already there in purchase.order.line. So either before my onchange or after it, it should continue with its standard functioning.

Thanks

**EDIT**: latest version (getting errors when any of the related many2one or selection fields has a value).

```
class purchase_order_line_custom(osv.osv):
    _name = 'purchase.order.line'
    _inherit = 'purchase.order.line'

    def onchange_product_id(self, cr, uid, ids, pricelist_id, product_id, qty, uom_id, partner_id, date_order=False, fiscal_position_id=False, date_planned=False, name=False, price_unit=False, context=None):
    values = super(purchase_order_line_custom, self).onchange_product_id(cr, uid, ids, pricelist_id, product_id, qty, uom_id, partner_id, date_order, fiscal_position_id, date_planned,name, price_unit, context=context)
    if product_id:
        product = self.pool.get('product.product').browse(cr, uid, product_id, context=context)
        values['value'].update({
                                'qualified_name':product.qualified_name,
                                'product_type' : product.product_type or None,
                                'product_subtype' : product.product_subtype,
                                'count_id':product.count_id or None 
        })
    return values   

_columns={
          'product_type': fields.related('product_id','product_type',type='selection', string='Product Type', selection=[('X','X'),('Y','Y'),('Z','Z')]),
          'product_subtype': fields.related('product_id','product_subtype',type='char', size=64, string='Sub-Type'),
          'qualified_name': fields.related('product_id','qualified_name',type='char', size=64, string='Qualified Name'),
          'count_id': fields.related('product_id','count_id',type='many2one',relation='product.mycount',string='Count')
          }

purchase_order_line_custom()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to overide the onchange function(you can use super() ) for the field 'product_id' and update the result.
for example

```
def onchange_product(self,cr,uid,ids,product_id,context=None):
    values = super(<your_class_name>,self).onchange_product(cr, uid,ids,product_id,context=context)
    # values will be a dictionary containing 'value' as a key.
    # You need to add all the newly added related fields and other fields to the values['value']. 
    # if 'aaa' is the newly added field, then values['value'].update({'aaa':<value for aaa>})
    # then return values
    return values
```

modify you onchange to the following

```
def onchange_product_id(self, cr, uid, ids, pricelist_id, product_id, qty, uom_id,
    partner_id, date_order=False, fiscal_position_id=False, date_planned=False,
    name=False, price_unit=False, context=None):
    values = super(purchase_order_line_custom, self).onchange_product_id(cr, uid, ids, pricelist_id, product_id, qty, uom_id, partner_id, date_order, fiscal_position_id, date_planned,name, price_unit, context=context)
    if product_id:
        product = self.pool.get('product.product').browse(cr, uid, product_id, context=context)
        values['value'].update({
            'product_type' : product.product_type,
            'product_subtype' : product.product_subtype,
            'qualified_name' : product.qualified_name,
            'count_id' : product.count_id                 
        })
    return values
```

Comment: Thanks but can you please indicate how an override is done. I searched in code for override examples but all I see is comments that say this method overrides that method etc. Does it work by name? If so I already tried that.

Comment: Also please consider that the super class in this case expects a host of arguments, whereas I don't need any arguments in my inherited onchange. So in order to call super, do I need to add all those arguments in my onchange arguments to pass them on?

Comment: @RazaAli Modified my answer. Please check it

Comment: I am already doing this. Please see my edit. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Thanks. The only difference is "values=" vs "values.update". I made this change. It does fill the base properties but not my ones. So it is not registering my override for some reason.

Comment: So the issue was an extra tab at function signature level. It's working now thanks to your advice. I'm still struggling with assigning values of a selection field (product_type) in the product to product_type in po line.

Answer (score 0):

First let's understand why `fields.related` is used?

`fields.related` field that points to some data inside another field of the current record.

That means, fields which are related will be filled automatically when you will select the value of other field.

Example:

```
   _columns = {
       'product_id': fields.many2one('product.product', 'Product'),
       'product_name': fields.related('product_id', 'name', type='char', string='Product Name'),
    }
```

In this example `product_name` will be filled automatically when you will select the `product_id`. You don't have to write `onchange` for that.

You can find many examples for `fields.related`.

Comment: That's what I expected but it wasn't populating until the whole record was saved. And I searched other places in code and found the use of onchange for the same reasons.